# Get product sizes php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

How can I get the product sizes for each product? I have two tables, where tblproduct have; `id, product_name, product_desc and product_image` and tblproduct_extension have; `id, product_price, product_stocks, product_size, product_id(id of tblproduct)`. Its working but it shows only one size.

Query:

```
$id = $_GET['view_product'];
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct LEFT JOIN tblproduct_extension ON tblproduct.id=tblproduct_extension.product_id WHERE tblproduct.id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Size</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['product_size'];?>"><?php echo $row['product_size'];?></option>
</select>
```

[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwViH.png)
[ProductExtension Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u08eI.png)

Comment: Read about SQL injection before you do anything else

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop throgh your array to show all product size 
Try this

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Size</option>
<?php foreach($row as $prod_row){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $prod_row['product_size'];?>"><?php echo $prod_row['product_size'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

You're using `$_GET[]` without any sanitization. It is absolutely terrible. Learn about `PDO` or `MYSQLI PARAMETERS`

Comment: Not working. Too many errors.

$_GET (<a href="details.php?view_product='.$row['id'].'&id='.$row['segment_id'].'">)